# How to make rsnapshot backups in different locations?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, rsnapshot

I have backup server that gathers backups from few other servers. I want to make directory structure like this

```
/backup/snapshots/<hostname>/<period>.0/<files>
```

Instead of default

```
/backup/snapshots/<period>.0/<hostname>/<files>
```

How to do this? I tried to specify parameter

```
backup  root@remote-host:/backup/snapshots/hourly.0        .       snapshot_root=/backup/snapshots/myhost/
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, rsnapshots only configuration for this is the "snapshot_root" directive.

Man page: "snapshot_root Local filesystem path to save all snapshots"

These are a few examples from: https://askubuntu.com/questions/20603/what-does-snapshot-root-do

> snapshot_root /var/backups/me
>
> ...
>
> backup /home/me/movies/ /media/
> backup /home/me/music/  /media/
> backup /home/me/drafts/ /documents/

After running rsnapshot hourly, for example, the snapshots would be
stored under

> /var/backups/me/hourly.0/media
> /var/backups/me/hourly.0/documents

So, pretty much what I'm saying is that I *belive* there's no easy way of changing that, and that you might need to change the source for this, but of course I  can be wrong and if that's the case, please ignore this answer.

Comment: Downvoting, because this answer is not helpful, stating an incorrect belief that the question can not be (easily) solved. (It can, see Dmitry's answer, which should be the accepted one.)

Answer (score 6):

You need to use another configuration file, where you can set different snapshot_root directory (and other backup params).

For example /etc/rsnapshot.additional.conf

After what you need to add to your rsnapshot cron file (if you use Ubuntu - you can find it /etc/cron.d/rsnapshot).

```
30 3    * * *       root    /usr/bin/rsnapshot daily
10 0  3    * * 1       root    /usr/bin/rsnapshot weekly
11 30 2    1 * *       root    /usr/bin/rsnapshot monthly
```

lines, like this

```
30 3    * * *       root    /usr/bin/rsnapshot -c /etc/rsnapshot.additional.conf daily
10 0  3    * * 1       root    /usr/bin/rsnapshot -c /etc/rsnapshot.additional.conf weekly
11 30 2    1 * *       root    /usr/bin/rsnapshot -c /etc/rsnapshot.additional.conf monthly
```

Which means that rsnapshot will be call two times with different config file and make two backups